# How to change time between counts in cycleCount JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I have a seamle code, that include mediaPlayer of JavaFX!
I set mediaPlayer.setCycleCounts **(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE)** and song repeat always! 
But between repeat cycles I have some little stop, in 0.5 sec! How to do this cycle without stops?

```
    private File mp3File;
    private Media media;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private MediaView mediaView;

    public SoundEngine(String mediaFile) {
        mp3File = new File(mediaFile);
        try {
            media = new Media(mp3File.toURI().toURL().toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your sound file has silent part at the end or begining. 
You can use `mediaPlayer.setStartTime(Duration.millies(500))` to skip the silent part if it is at the begining of the file.